# Remove FAILURES from pytest output

Tags: python, pytest

Pytest is new to me. We try to verify that we have all expected files in a project.

I like every part of the pytest output except for the detailed FAILURES that will confuse our non-programmers.

How can we suppress the FAILURES output?

**Current code:**

```
import os.path
import pytest

spec = {"expected_files": ["Dockerfile", "Duckerfile", "Daskerfile"]}

@pytest.mark.parametrize("expected_file", spec['expected_files'])
def test_expected_file_is_in_project(expected_file):
    assert os.path.isfile(expected_file), "File \""+expected_file+"\" not found in project"
```

**Output after running the "pytest -v" command**

[image: Output after running the "pytest -v" command]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may run `pytest` with the traceback (`tb`) option set to `no` in order to suppress the traceback reporting, i.e.:

```
pytest --tb=no
```

Check out the [Modifying Python traceback printing](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#modifying-python-traceback-printing) section of the `pytest` documentation.